# What does it take to be accepted to FUN?

Tags: conferences

I've just understood that FUN's deadline is slowly approaching. The conference page is very vague about what kind of fun they are looking for. So the question is: what the FUN committee is looking for?

Comment: Why don't you contact the organizers directly?

Comment: A link to the website could help.

Comment: Have a look at the proceedings from previous editions of the conference. You will notice that there are many different ways in which a paper can be fun. Being witty is only one of them.

Comment: @IgorShinkar: The website of the 8th International Conference on Fun with Algorithms is here: http://www2.idsia.ch/cms/fun16/